# Toolbox Xamarin Studio and monoDevelop on mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, monodevelop, xamarin-studio, toolbox

So in my class, which part design and part programming, we are now heading to the subject of C# and asp.net programming.

The professor is using Visual Studio 2010. I'm on a macbook pro, and hoped that I didn't have to use Bootcamp to install Visual Studio. I found the MonoDevelop solution where you download Xamarin Studio. When i'm trying to build and asp.net website there is no tools in the toolbox? I really need toolbox.

Comment: If you're going to require Visual Studio features, it sounds like you'd be better off with Visual Studio...

Comment: you are better getting VS and maybe a windows laptop.

Comment: Yeah! that not going to happen :)
The c# is only for this project, so i don't wanna buy a laptop for one project ;) You guys actually have some solutions to my problem?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to find a free solution for your problem? I'm also stuck with a Macbook and some .NET projects :/

Comment: @DARKGuy - since i asked the question, i have bought a windows laptop with visual studio. In the mean time microsoft has starting developing visual studio to mac. Maybe you can give that a look: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/